# Save EditItemTemplate DropDownList to Database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, gridview, entity-framework-4

I have a Entity Data Model which abstracts an underlying MSSQL database. I have an EntityDataSource which is wired up to a GridView. The GridView has a number of columns - most are BoundFields, but one is an EditItemTemplate. Inside of this template I've placed the following:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EditRoleDataSource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="name=pbu_checklistEntities"
    DefaultContainerName="pbu_checklistEntities" EnableFlattening="false"
    EntitySetName="Roles" />

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoles" runat="server" DataSourceID="EditRoleDataSource"
    DataTextField="RoleName" DataValueField="ID" OnInit="ddlRoles_Init" />
```

The code executes okay and I can click edit and change the selected dropdownlist, but when I click the Update button in the GridView it doesn't update the value in the database with the datavaluefield value from the edititemtemplate. How can I get it to save the selected value from the edititemtemplate to the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the binding of the DropDownList's `SelectedValue` is missing. Assuming that you are in a grid or form to edit a `User` which has a `RoleID` property to refer to the assigned role, this could look like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoles" runat="server" DataSourceID="EditRoleDataSource"
    DataTextField="RoleName" DataValueField="ID" OnInit="ddlRoles_Init" 
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("RoleID") %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

The EntityDataSource has to specify EnableUpdate="true". Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488551.aspx).

Comment: EnableUpdate is already set to true for the EntityDataSource of the GridView, that entitydatasource is only for populating the dropdownlist...